# Get cellEditorParams Values from Server side API

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Can somebody suggest a way to get values in cellEditorParams from an api for agRichSelectCellEditor.

what i have is

```
{
                headerName: "Name",
                field: "Name",
                cellRenderer: 'keyValueCellRenderer',
                cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
                cellEditorParams: (params) => {
                     let url ='/customers/new-customers;
                     if (params.data.CustomerType && params.data.CustomerType.Id)
                        url = url + '?type=' + params.data.CustomerType.Id;
                     // get data from url and have it pushed to editor select list

                },
                 keyCreator: keyValueFilter,
                filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
                editable: true, sortable: true
            },

function keyValueFilter(param) {
    return param.data && param.data.Text ? param.data.Text : ''
}
```

I have seen example for 'Reference Data' on ag-grid but that seems simple as data are already available before editing.

This code is in plain javascript but a solution in angular would be fine too.

Code (sorry it working in editor, not sure how use stackblitz )
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-a4dkax

Thanks

Comment: can you put your issue on stackblitz.io

Comment: Hi @harkeshkumar tried to setup but couldn't get it working. sorry never done it so not sure how those editors works. would you mind looking at it. I have added link into description

Comment: yes sure i can look om it